# How to convert String to JSON in Swift

Tags: swift

I am receiving text from a web socket. And I want to convert the text to JSON.

Text received from the socket:

`{'id': 920, 'location': {'lat': 11.0368754733495, 'lon': -47.203396772120247}}`

Tried this:

```
 func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String) {
        print("got some text: \(text)")
        let data = Data(text.utf8)
        do {
            // make sure this JSON is in the format we expect
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                // try to read out a string array
                if let id = json["id"] as? Int {
                    print(id)
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

But I am getting `Failed to load: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.` error.

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid JSON. The keys must be wrapped in double quotes.

You can replace the single quotes with double quotes on the fly

```
let data = Data(text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\'", with: "\"").utf8)
```

Side note:

Never print `.localizedDescription` in `JSONSerialization`/`JSONDecoder` `catch` blocks. And bridge casting to `NSError` is redundant

```
catch {
    print("Failed to load:", error)
}
```